# SQL Group By Multiple columns & multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by

Here is my tables

```
CREATE TABLE Course(Cno CHAR(6), Cname NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(Cno))
CREATE TABLE SC(Sno CHAR(7) NOT NULL,Cno CHAR(6) NOT NULL,Grade TINYINT,
    PRIMARY KEY(Sno, Cno),
    FOREIGN KEY(Sno) REFERENCES Student(Sno),
    FOREIGN KEY(Cno) REFERENCES Course(Cno)
)
```

table Course

```
Cno    Cname    
------------
C001   Math
C002   CS
C003   Database
```

table SC

```
Sno    Cno    Grade
-------------------
1      C001   80
2      C002   90
2      C003   70
3      C002   60
```

Want...:

```
Cno    Cname    Number
-----------------------
C002   CS       2
C001   Math     1
C003   Database 1
```

this code is worked

```
select top 3 with ties Course.Cno, Course.Cname, count(SC.Cno) AS Number 
from Course left join SC
  on Course.Cno = SC.Cno
  group by Course.Cno, Cname, Semester
  order by count(SC.Cno) desc
```

but if I use "goup by Course.Cno", not worked..

Why I must add "Cname, Semester"?

---

I tried on mysql worked..but sql server 2012 not.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL Server?

Comment: yep..mysql is worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a sub-query to get the count:

```
select Cno, Cname, (select count(*) from sc where c.cno = sc.cno) as cnt
from Course as c
order by cnt
```

Comment: Many Thanks. sub-query is worked. if I want to order by count(*). `select Cno, Cname, (select count(*) from sc where c.cno = sc.cno) as number from Course as C order by number desc)`. Could you explain group by one column is not worked. Thank you ~

Comment: @0neSe7en, try and remove Semester from the GROUP BY, and use count(*) in the select-list. Do also ORDER BY Number DESC.